# Grails: Cannot invoke method production() on null object

Tags: grails, nullpointerexception

Here is my `Config.groovy`'s environments section (using 2.3.6):

```
grails.app.context = "/"

environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080"
    } production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        grails.serverURL = "http://myapp.example.io"  // Although this isn't my production domain, it is a *.io TLD
    }
}
```

When I do a `grails -Dgrails.env=development run-app` I get:

> | Error Error packaging application: Error loading Config.groovy: Cannot invoke method production() on null object (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `production` DSL in a new line. If used in the same line as the closure for development ends, then it is treated as a new method call on the return type of `development` call (which is void) with a closure param. The method name being `production` like:

```
development(clos1).production(clos2)
```

VERSUS

```
development(closure)
production(closure)
```

So use it as:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080"
    } 
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        grails.serverURL = "http://myapp.example.io"
    }
}
```

Also, you do not need to specify the environment as `development` for run-app, default environment is development, so just `grails run-app` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks @dmahaptro (+1) - just curious here, what actual process is responsible for parsing this DSL? What process/component is (as you say) treating my `production` DSL as a new method call? Is this something in Groovy, Grails or something else entirely? Thanks again!

Comment: This is a syntactic sugar provided by groovy to build DSL where method calls can represented without braces. Example: `method(a, b)` can also be invoked as `method a, b`.